# Jquery click affects more divs than it should

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Got this piece of code for a dropdown textarea. Goal is to have div.card show/hide when the checkbox is clicked, and this works, but clicking div.card itself makes it hide itself, how could I prevent this from happening?

Jquery looks like this

```
$('.options .checkbox').click(function(){ 
    $('.options .card').toggleClass("hidden").toggleClass("show");
});
```

HTML looks like this

```
<label>
Label description
<strong>
    + € 0,50
</strong>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <div class="card hidden">
        <textarea>
        </textarea>
    </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the click event from bubbling up to the parent:

```
$('.card').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Or, you could verify that the target element is really the one you're after:

```
$('.options .checkbox').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('checkbox')) return false; 

    $('.options .card').toggleClass("hidden").toggleClass("show");
});
```

Comment: I get what that should do, but both pieces of code still leave me with the same problem. Any other possible reasons for this?

Comment: Do you have any event handlers hooked up to the cards?

Comment: This is the only jquery I'm currently using for the site, aside from a sidebar height function that has nothing to do with this. So no, just the code I posted

Comment: Just looked over your HTML again. A `<label>` element basically makes the clickable area for your `<input>` bigger. You'll have to get rid of the label to get this to work.